# Specify limits to a plane's dimension, depending on data dimensions, so it exactly overlaps data

Tags: image, matlab, plot, 3d, plane

In MATLAB, I am plotting a plane which should overlap with 3D data available. In certain cases (as shown below), the plane's dimension becomes too large. How can I specify the dimensions of the plane so that it more or less overlaps with my data and does not appear very huge?

Is it in the meshgrid function? What should the input be? This dimension should adapt to all my other (but similar) data.

[image]

I have attached the functions [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/q2m9505xmehc0r6/AABd8hT1O0aoDYJl6bselutRa?dl=0) .

This is how you can use the functions:

```
DisplayReconstructedScene( PointCloud3D, J1 ); hold on
load('n,V and p.mat')
[ n,V,p,x,y,z ] = Display_Plane(n, V, p);
```